# Cron Script Length

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I have a backup script, a script that cyncs file with other files on my computer, and a script that uploads files to my website with ncftp. I used cron to load .sh files, and my shorter scripts work, but my scripts that take long (My FTP upload script and backup script) don't run.
Here's my crontab file:

```
0 0 * * * ./Desktop/Backup.sh
*/5 * * * * ./Desktop/File_Sync.sh
*/5 * * * * ./Desktop/File_Upload.sh
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking but...right off my top of head: 2 questions:  1.  have you tried running it one at a time and time the length of script execution?  2.  Have you considered using SSH method instead of FTP?  I run a backup almost similar to yours but via SSH purely.

Answer (score 1):

There is no time limit in cron jobs, if that what your'e asking. The problem must be somewhere else.
Try to add `set -vx` in your scripts, and redirect output to a file:

```
./Desktop/Backup.sh > /tmp/Backup.log 2>&1
```

Many times the problem with cron jobs is that the user login script is not executed. Try to add `source ~/.bash_login` (If bash) in the beginning of the script.

Also, use absolute path in the cron (Not an error, more of best practice)